# Beziehungen: as "attitude towards"

Tags: dialect, yiddish

In Yiddish the word *baziehungen* of course means relationships as it does in German, but it can also mean "attitude towards", which I don't think is found in German. I came across the phrase "the attitude towards the Jews on the part of the Christian population" which put the question in my head: how would you say it in German?

> “die Baziehungen zu Jüden *m’tzad* (Heb. “on the part of) die
>   kristlecher Bevölkerung”

It's also peculiar because I can't think how to express the concept "on the part of" for which Yiddish uses a Hebrew term. Usually there is a German synonym which if not widespread is at least universally understood (e.g. *gesicht* for "punim" and *krieg* for "milkhommah"). I wonder if anyone would care to comment on this?

Answer (score 2):

The German term "Beziehung" covers multiple aspects of relationship, and beside being the plural, "Beziehungen" has some additional meanings. However, while you might tell or guess an attitude towards somebody from a persons "Beziehung" to that other person, you would not denote it that way but would use "Haltung", "Einstellung", "Gesinnung", or "Verhalten":

> ...die *Einstellung* der christlichen Bevölkerung zu den Juden

indicates what the Christian population predominantly think about the Jews and their relationship towards them. This does not necessarily imply an interaction.

> ...die *Gesinnung* der christlichen Bevölkerung gegenüber den Juden

is a little bit outdated and only used in a highly formal context. It mainly signifies a basic moral, religious, and political position.

> ...die *Haltung* der christlichen Bevölkerung gegenüber den Juden

may already imply or include decisions how to act, e.g. to be solidary or not, and rather describes a current attitude as opposed to a general one.

> ...das *Verhalten* der christlichen Bevölkerung gegenüber den Juden

relates to the actual behaviour, including interaction.

"On the part of" is the equivalent of the German "seitens":

> ...die Haltung gegenüber den Juden seitens der christlichen Bevölkerung

The English and Yiddish sentence construction with "on the part of" would, however, be used only in a comparative context when also other groups would be involved, e.g.:

> Die Einstellung der muslimischen Bevölkerung... Verändert hat sich jedoch die Haltung gegenüber den Juden seitens der christlichen Bevölkerung.